# Found $id field without a $ref before it, which is invalid

Tags: database, mongodb

I have this kind of documents in my mongodb (3.4):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588e7a5951fa0982213c8f72"),
    "content" : "This is example"
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("5867822e10031569325c87b4"),
    "title" : "Notifications",
    "community" : NumberLong(7),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-18T22:10:37.795Z"),
    "tags" : [ 
        null, 
        {
            "type" : "question",
            "$ref" : "tag",
            "$id" : ObjectId("588e7a5951fa0982213c8f73"),
            "$db" : "forum"
        }, 
        {
            "$id" : ObjectId("588e7a5951fa0982213c8f74"),
            "$db" : "forum",
            "type" : "question",
            "$ref" : "tag"
        }
    ],
    "status" : "opened",
    "pinned" : false
}
```

I want to remove `null` from `tags` array, so I tried this query:

```
db.getCollection('question').update(
    { _id : ObjectId("588e7a5951fa0982213c8f72") },
    { $pullAll: { tags: [null] } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

But, I got this error:

> Found $id field without a $ref before it, which is invalid.

**[Edit]**

I found that `$id` and `$ref` is out of sequence in the third record of the `tags` field. So, can I fix the sequence and remove `null` using update query?

Comment: any reply, please. I also faced this issue. :(